# Adaptive Cards - selectAction didn't work on MS Teams App on iOS devices Node.js

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to build a chat bot on both PC and mobile using **Adaptive Cards**.

I need my card to render as a **list of choices**, and whenever user taps on choice, the data of that choice will be sent to me.
My card just like this:

```
var card = {
"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
"content": {
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Choice 1"
                }
            ],
            "selectAction": {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Submit action",
                "data": {
                    "info": "Data of choice 1"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Choice 2"
                }
            ],
            "selectAction": {
                "type": "Action.Submit",
                "title": "Submit action",
                "data": {
                    "info": "Data of choice 2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The selectAction worked just smoothly until I updated the latest version on App Store. I keep tapping but I get nothing.

Note that this action is still working on Android devices and PC.

Any idea for this situation? Or pls help me to fix this bug.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen for cards sent on a channel conversation as well?

Comment: Hi Jacob. This happened for Adaptive Cards only, the others work well, as I know.

Comment: @LeGiang - Is this happening for 1:1 conversation or channel conversation?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Hi there, it's happening on 1:1 conversation. I also raised this issue on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/1911) but it hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your card json does not look correct. For Adaptive cards in Teams, refer to the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-actions#adaptive-card-actions

```
{
  "type": "Action.Submit",
  "title": "Click me for messageBack",
  "data": {
    "msteams": {
        "type": "messageBack",
        "displayText": "I clicked this button",
        "text": "text to bots",
        "value": "{\"bfKey\": \"bfVal\", \"conflictKey\": \"from value\"}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your answer. I did tried yours but nothing changed :( Thanks anyway!